# Anonymous site ask for credentials

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, anonymous-authentication

I have made a Web application to be accessed by anonymous user. The site collection's Home page is accessible by anonymous user in browser and windows phone. But when anonymous user tries to access the site in Android and iPhone devices, it asks for authentication and the SharePoint's authentication screen appears.

**Actual result**: The site must be accessible by anonymous user in Android and iPhone devices without authentication.

Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For this, add within the web.config file of the WebApp in the section configuration/system.web:

```
   <browserCaps>
  <result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, 
   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  <filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
  </browserCaps>
```